# I have error "cudaGetDevice() failed. Status: initialization error for CNN Model

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, gpu

i'm new in Tensorflow and CNN.

2 Days Ago, i tried to run Jupyter Notebook on GPU, and it work, yesterday until now, i tried to run the notebook again, but i get this error message:

`InternalError: cudaGetDevice() failed. Status: initialization error`

So I tried to use Google Collab and run it again with GPU in Google  Collab. But turns out I got the same error again.

Here is the full error i get:

[image]

I don't understand what is happening, and what is the meaning behind all those codes.
I tried different model architecture and it's the same.

What should I do to fix this error? Thank You

Answer (score 0):

If you have any environment about tensorflow, uninstall it and install tensorflow to the base(root)

1. conda activate base
2. conda install -c anaconda pip
3. pip install tensorflow